# Retrieving values from buttons

Tags: iphone

I have some buttons and i want to place individual letter in each button, and after placing all letters in all buttons,i have to form a word and check with the database.How should i get the values from buttons and form like a word.
Any help is appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, it's not great for localization, you'd be better off tagging the button ( = giving it a number in interface builder), reading that number from code `button.tag == your number` and do the work from there.

Answer (score 2):

you can get title of button with bellow code..

```
NSString *strButtonTitle = yourButton.titleLabel.text;
```

and also you can set title to Button with bellow code..

```
[yourButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: But i have images on that place and whenever we place next image on button it should recognize the previous button and next image is placing next to previous placed button.

Comment: oh you mean you want to get value which write on the image??

Comment: ha exactly,i placed image so i can get the value from dictionary,my problem is on first button i placed a.png which value is a,and on next button i placed t.png which value is t,then two buttons recognize and if word form it will check with database

Comment: but for your this requirement you can easily assign that value on the button with that type of letters array or dictionory so you will easily get that value.. its better for your this requirement...

Comment: and you want to just change that image from one button to other right?? mean if Button1 have a a.png then just change it to t.png right??

Comment: but im not getting how to get the strings from both two buttons and displaying those word

Comment: see instead of use this type of different image just set plain image in background and set value with this code.. [yourButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; and then you can get easily that value with this code... NSString *strButtonTitle = yourButton.titleLabel.text;

Comment: This is not very portable

Answer (score 0):

The most reusable solution would be to:

- add all of your buttons to an array (you can do this in interface builder)

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
  ```
- as you set the image on a button set the corresponding text value in another array

  ```
  NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

  [imageNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [self.buttons[idx] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [values addObject:name];
  }];

  self.values = [values copy];
  ```

Now when the user taps a button you can use the position of the button in the `buttons` array to determine the corresponding text value;

```
    - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button
    {
      NSInteger index = [self.buttons indexOfObject:button];
      NSLog(@"textValue: %@", self.values[index]); // I don't know how you are mapping imageName to values but this will give you the image name
    }
```

Comment: after doing like this its showing an empty array